# PHP chaining error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, chaining

Is a good idea throw exceptions on chained methods?

For example:

```
class Mailer(){

    private $attachment;

    public function addAttachment($attachment){
        if($this->validateAttachment($attachment)){
            $this->attachment = $attachment;
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid attachment');
    }

    public function send(){
        [...]
    }

    private function validateAttachment($attachment){
        if($attachment === 'test'){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

$mailer = new Mailer();
$mailer->addAttachment('invalid')->send();
```

Of course, this will fail and cause a fatal error unless we use try / catch.

Otherwise, if we don't thrown an error when `addAttachment` fails, use will not notice if anything went wrong. 
And if the `send` can work without attachments, we cannot return an error on that method neither.

So, there is any good practice on error logging / handling when using chained methods?

Answer (score 1):

You should throw an Exception anywhere you want to interrupt the flow of the program. It doesn't matter if it's chained or not. In your case, if the adding of the attachment fails, you want to stop it before it reaches `send()`. That's a perfectly fine use of an Exception.

Obviously, you need to make sure you wrap the whole execution in `try`/`catch` or you'll get a Fatal error (where all PHP stops).